# Promise is not resolved to a value?

Tags: javascript, promise, ecmascript-6

I can't find my mistake in the following code.
All I want is save() to return true or false but its always `undefined`

```
function mypromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("it worked")
  })
}

function save() {
  mypromise().then(success => {
    return true
  }, error => {
    return false
  });
}

var saveSuccessful = save();
console.log('success', saveSuccessful) // undefined ?
```

Comment: code inside your callbacks is executed asynchronously.

Comment: Your function `save()` does not return anything - what did you expect?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum When I do `save mypromise().then()` I get the pending Promise back. Is there a way to return the value directly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Your `save` function returns nothing. Please make sure, don't missed to return promise out of here. Then you should use `.then` to check whether save was success or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll know if the save is successful only when the promise has finished executing, like so:

```
function mypromise() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("it worked")
  })
}

function save() {
  mypromise().then(success => {
    console.log('success');
    return true;
  }, error => {
    return false
  });
}

save();
```

If you could write `var saveSuccessful = save();` that would mean that `save()` is *synchronous*, by definition of synchronous, but you explicitely want it to be *asynchronous*.

Comment: And see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call for more details.